# Visual Basic Implementation of Merge Sort yields result with 0 Mixed In

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement a basic Merge Sort algorithm in Visual Basic through a console application.  I think the below code is commented well enough to explain how I am trying to solve the problem.  My issue is that I get a zero added into my Integer array after my first merge().  The array is sorted properly, but I need help figuring out where that zero is coming from.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    'Keep console open until Escape key is pressed
    Do Until (Console.ReadKey.Key = ConsoleKey.Escape)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the length of the array to be sorted")

        Dim input = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim inputLength As Integer
        inputLength = CInt(input)
        Dim array(inputLength) As Integer

        ' Initialize the random-number generator.
        Randomize()

        For index As Integer = 0 To inputLength - 1
            ' Generate random value between 1 and 5000. 
            array(index) = CInt(Int((5000 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("The unsorted array is: ")
        'Write the randomnly filled array
        For index2 As Integer = 0 To inputLength - 1
            Console.Write(array(index2) & " ")
        Next
        'Print dashed line
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------")

        MergeSort(array, 0, array.Length - 1)
    Loop

End Sub


Sub MergeSort(ByVal array() As Integer, lowIndex As Integer, highIndex As Integer)

    If (lowIndex < highIndex) Then
        Dim midIndex = Math.Floor((lowIndex + highIndex) / 2)    'ensure that we get integer result i.e. 5/2 yields 2
        'Recursively break apart original array until the tree bottoms out
        MergeSort(array, lowIndex, midIndex)
        MergeSort(array, midIndex + 1, highIndex)
        'Then merge our single element arrays
        Merge(array, lowIndex, midIndex, highIndex)
    End If

End Sub

Sub Merge(ByVal array() As Integer, lowIndex As Integer, midIndex As Integer, highIndex As Integer)
    'creating 2 sub arrays for left hand and right hand part of merge

    Dim n1 = midIndex - lowIndex + 1
    Dim n2 = highIndex - midIndex

    Dim L(n1) As Integer
    Dim R(n2) As Integer

    'creating index variable to keep track of final answer
    Dim k As Integer = lowIndex

    Dim counterI = 0
    Dim counterJ = 0
    'Fill each of the two arrays declared

    While (counterI < n1)
        L(counterI) = array(lowIndex + counterI)
        counterI = counterI + 1
    End While


    While (counterJ < n2)
        R(counterJ) = array(midIndex + 1 + counterJ)
        counterJ = counterJ + 1
    End While

    'Reset index variables
    k = lowIndex
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0

    'Go through and compare the two subarrays and fill index k of our answer
    'with the lower value until one of the subarrays is empty
    While (i < n1 And j < n2)

        If (L(i) <= R(j)) Then
            array(k) = L(i)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            array(k) = R(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        k = k + 1
    End While

    'If one array is empty we go ahead and fill our answer with remaining array
    'this removes the sentinels from example (I was struggling with index bounds)

    While (i < n1)
        array(k) = L(i)
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
    End While

    While (j < n2)
        array(k) = R(j)
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    End While

    'Print our answer
    Console.WriteLine("The sorted array using Merge Sort is: ")
    For index2 As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        Console.Write(array(index2) & " ")
    Next
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: `Dim array(inputLength) As Integer` - In VB, declaring the array like this will results in `array` having (inputLength + 1) elements.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!  Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputLength` is one less than `array.Length`. When you initialize array and write its initial values, you go from 0 to `inputLength - 1`. When you write the sorted array, you go from 0 to `array.Length - 1`, which outputs an additional member of the array. It's zero because it is uninitialized.